# Applying bullet to specific sentence using Word Interop with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm working on automating word documents and I need to insert bullet points before sentences that start with the string "BUG". The "User" and "Status" sentences are not a part of the bullet format. The result should look like this:

[image]

But my code generates this:

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code (The content has already been written to the document. This should have been a simple find and insert bullet with indent.):

```
             // Iterate through the document to find sentences starting with "BUG".
             for (int i = 1; i < letterHeadDoc.Sentences.Count; i++)
             {
                 if (letterHeadDoc.Sentences[i].Text.StartsWith("BUG")) 
                 {
                     //MessageBox.Show(letterHeadDoc.Sentences[i].Text.ToString());
                     letterHeadDoc.Sentences[i].ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
                 }
             }
```

I'm stumped because inside the if-statement that checks if the sentence starts with "BUG", I've outputted the sentence and it indeed returns the sentence that starts with "BUG".

So why is it inserting the bullet before the sentence "Version 1.0"?

Can anybody tell me why ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault(); is inserting the bullet before the sentence "Version 1.0" instead of the "Bug" sentence? Also, why does the bullet format (indentation) continue onto every sentence after "Version 1.0"?

Comment: Based on how Word behaves via UI you'd need to get sentence into separate paragraph first...

Comment: Can that be done after all of the content has been written or should it be done beforehand?

Comment: When each sentence is written to the document, "\r" is appended to it. Shouldn't this specify the start of a new paragraph? I've tried \r\n and System.Environment.NewLine as well and they all produce the same results.

Comment: justin, I'd recommend updating the post itself with your findings - edits push posts to home page so more people will see it. (my initial comment was strictly based on my regular usage of Word to edit, I have not used Word interop to know answer to your question).